# How to write a piece of program to make CPU busy at a certain level on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm considering writing a testing tool used to make the CPU busy at a specified level on Linux, say 80% usage. How can I do this? It doesn't matter if this tool is a script or a c++ program.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [stress](http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/) program. You can also use the `cpuburn` suite, in Ubuntu (or Debian):

```
apt-get install cpuburn
```

Answer (score 0):

For a platform-independent solution, you can compile and run one or more instances of this C++11 program, with a command-line argument fine-tuned for the desired percentage of CPU usage.

```
//
// Application to sleep for nanoseconds specified by command-line argument
//

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  if (argc >= 2) {
    std::istringstream iss(argv[1]);
    unsigned int interval;
    if (iss >> interval)
      for(uint64_t i=0; i<std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max(); i++)
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(interval));
  }
}
```